# Decode HTML entities with SED or AWK

Tags: awk, sed, terminal, entities

I am working on Mac trying to decode a simple line like

```
$var='doc_input'
$textToChange='&lt;div&gt; &lt;doc_input/&gt; &lt/div&gt;' 
echo $textToChange | sed -e s=\&lt\;$var\/\&gt\;=\<$var\/\>=g
```

to

```
&lt;div&gt; <doc_input/> &lt;/div&gt;
```

it will work. The result has to be mixed up with encoded and decoded entities.

But if I try to write it in a file it will not work. The file a.txt contains the text.

```
sed -e s=\&lt\;$var\/\&gt\;=\<$var\/\>=g a.txt > c.txt
```

The output is the same as the input.
Please how do I have to proceed?

Comment: Is there anybody having an idea for me?

Comment: can you use the form `sed -f mysedScript a.txt > c.txt`. If yes, try `echo "s=\&lt\;$var\/\&gt\;=\<$var\/\>=g" > mysedScript` . It worked for me. Else edit your Q to show output of `sed --version ; echo BASH_VERSION=$BASH_VERSION` . Good luck.

Comment: But, I agree with the advice (now missing) to use `xmlstarlet` or other appropriate editor. You can solve your current problem with `sed` but now your boss will think `sed` is always the correct solution and "why is this taking so long and why doesn't it solve for special case Y or Z!?" :-) OK? Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I found no solution with sed to change in an external file  < to the symbol '<'. So I use now perl to  handle the change.

The solution is:

```
perl -pi -e 's/[&]{1}[l]{1}[t]{1}[;]{1}/$1</g' ./tmp.txt
perl -pi -e 's/[&]{1}[l]{1}[g]{1}[;]{1}/$1>/g' ./tmp.txt
```